# Fourier series of $|\sin(x)|,$ confusing $a_0$ and $\frac{1}{2}a_0.$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

So according to definition, the fourier series for an even function $f(x)$ is given by

$$f(x)=a_0+\sum_{n\in N}a_n\cos\left(\frac{\pi n x}{L}\right)\tag1$$
where
$$a_0=\frac{1}{2L}\int\limits_{-L}^{L}f(x)dx,\tag2$$
$$a_n=\frac{1}{L}\int\limits_{-L}^{L}f(x)\cos\left(\frac{\pi n x}{L}\right)\tag3dx$$

For $f(x)=|\sin(x)|$ we have that $2L=\pi\Leftrightarrow L=\pi/2.$ So

$$a_0=\frac{1}{\pi}\int\limits_{\pi/2}^{-\pi/2}|\sin(x)|dx=\frac{1}{\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{\pi}\sin(x)dx=\frac{2}{\pi}.\tag4$$

Also

$$a_n=\frac{2}{\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{\pi}\sin(x)\cos(nx)dx=\frac{2((-1)^{n+1}-1)}{\pi(n^2-1)}, \quad n\in\mathbb{N}.\tag 5$$

This means that

$$a_n=\left\{
  \begin{array}{rcr}
    0 & \text{if} & n&=&2k+1 \\
    -\frac{4}{\pi(n^2-1)} & \text{if} & n&=&2k \\
  \end{array}, \quad k\in\mathbb{N}
\right.\tag6$$

So using only the even values of $n$ we get that

$$|\sin(x)|=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(2kx)}{4k^2-1}.\tag{7}$$

Keep in mind that these answers are verified to be correct. Obsiously, if I plug in $n=0$ in $(6)$ I should get $a_0=\pi/2$, however when I do this, I get $a_0=\pi/4.$ I don't understand why?

Comment: $$f(x)=\dfrac{a_0}2+\sum_{n\in N}a_n\cos\left(\frac{\pi n x}{L}\right)\\a_0=\frac1L\int_{-L}^{L}f(x)dx=4/\pi$$You also have an error in $a_n$:$$a_n=\frac{2}{\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{\pi}\sin(x)\cos(2nx)dx=-\dfrac4{(4n^2-1)\pi}$$

Comment: So this guys has written wrong formulas then? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x04dnqg-iPw About the error in $a_n$, indeed, its a typo, I forgot the $4$.

Comment: Writing it this way is not wrong, per se. The constant term in Fourier series is written $a_0/2$ so that the general formula for $a_n$ is applicable for $n=0$. You can chose to call $a_0$ what I call $a_0/2$, but be careful that if you do, the general formula for $a_n$ no longer applies for $n=0$. Rather, what you'll get for $n=0$ using the formula will be $2a_0$ for you.